# LWC With Apex Wrapper class to Display current user and its Contact

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm writing an LWC using Apex Wrapper Class. I'm, stuck in editing the JS and HTML for this. Can y'all please help with the same? Basically, I want to display like this:

The User is: [Current user name]
The Contact is: [Its associated contact]

Here is the code I've written:

1. Apex controller+Wrapper class:

   ```java
   public with sharing class CurrentUserandContactController {
       @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
       public static WClass theMethod(){

           List<User> u = [SELECT Account.Name, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
           list<Contact> c = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id =: u[0].ContactId];
           WClass gudObj =  new WClass(u[0].Account.Name, c[0].Name);
           return gudObj;

       }

       public class WClass {
           @AuraEnabled
           public String usr{get; set;}
           @AuraEnabled
           public String ctct{get; set;}

           public WClass(String u, String ctct){
               this.usr = u;
               this.ctct = ctct;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Javascript

   ```js
   import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
   import theMethod from '@salesforce/apex/CurrentUserandContactController.theMethod';

   export default class Store_Detailz extends LightningElement {
       @track aVar = [];
       contact;
       user;

       @wire(theMethod)
       aMtd(Data, Error){
           if(Data){
               this.aVar = Data;
               this.user = aVar[0];
               this.contact = aVar[1];
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. HTML

   ```html
   <template>
       <p>
           User is: {user}
           Contact is: {contact}
       </p>
   </template>
   ```

Comment: You need to change the wire function to receive `{data, error}` and make sure to use `data` as the name. JavaScript is case sensitive and you need to receive the correct JavaScript object with the correct names when [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: This site is a repository of community-based knowledge. Even after your problem is solved, the question needs to remain as it is. The hope is that it can help other people with similar issues in the future. Think of it as the price you pay for getting help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to programming, I'm going to give you more help than you asked for...

First, get your indentation under control. Messy code is hard to read. Almost every IDE has a way to make your code pretty. For VS Code, the Format Document function is your friend. For the Salesforce Developer Console, you can select all your code and use Shift+Tab to make it pretty.

Second, variable names can be 40 characters long. `ctct` means nothing, while `contactName` is expressive and clearly tells anyone reading your code what is meant by this. Don't be stingy with your variable names; this isn't the 1980s where you could only use variable names that were 2 letters long.

Third, I'd suggest you avoid using underscores in your LWC names; it makes it so you have to write awkward `<c-store_detailz>` for no good reason. Use `TitleCase` for class names, and `camelCase` for properties. Avoid using excessive uppercase letters, because something like `MY_WONDERFUL_PROPERTY` will have to be written as `-m-y_-w-o-n-d-e-r-f-u-l_-p-r-o-p-e-r-t-y` when used in a template, which is not very legible and a pain to type.

Fourth, your Apex can be shortened to just a few lines of code. Here's my rendition of your Apex code:

```
public class CurrentUserAndContactController {
  @AuraEnabled public static Map<String, String> theMethod() {
    User currentUser = [
      SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.Name 
      FROM User 
      WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    ];
    return new Map<String, String> {
      'accountName' => currentUser.Contact.Account.Name,
      'contactName' => currentUser.Contact.Name
    };
  }
}
```

Using wrappers are fine, but when you're just getting started learning, keeping things simple is ideal.

Finally, four important things about JavaScript. First, JavaScript is case sensitive. That means that you absolutely need to make sure everything is capitalized correctly everywhere. Second, you need to pay attention to parameters. `(Data, Error)` is not the same as `({ data, error })`. Third, when you reference a variable or function in a class, you always need to use `this.`. Fourth, you need to remember the structure of your data between the client and server. You tried to access `aVar[0]`, but it should have been something like `this.aVar.usr`.

Here's my rendition of your controller, noting that I didn't change the component name only to keep things simple.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import theMethod from '@salesforce/apex/CurrentUserandContactController.theMethod';

export default class Store_Detailz extends LightningElement {
    aVar;
    contact;
    user;
    
    @wire(theMethod) userDataHandler({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.aVar = data;
            this.user = data.accountName;
            this.contact = data.contactName;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed answer, Sir. I copied and pasted and added the LWC in my store experience builder. There I'm only getting the display as:

`User is: Contact is:`

Please help me with this. Thanks a lot, again.

Comment: @SForce_User Are you logged in as a Community User? If not, I'd expect you to see nothing.

Comment: Yes. I click `Log in to Experience as User`. There I see this. Can you please tell me if there are any corrections I need to make in my HTML? Or if you can help me with an apt HTML for this, It'd be even great. Please do help. @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive. Make sure you use the correct case. Salesforce returns to your wire handler function an object containing `data` and `error` properties, so these are the names you must use when destructuring the object. Change your code to:

```js
    @wire(theMethod)
    aMtd({data, error}){
        if(data){
            this.aVar = data;
            this.user = this.aVar.usr;
            this.contact = this.aVar.ctct;
        }
    }
```

Note that I made sure that the `data` (stored into `aVar` - likely unnecessary) was assumed to be a `WClass` instance with the `usr` and `ctct` properties.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting the error:
`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error: [aVar0 is not defined]] Failing descriptor: {markup://force:ldsBindings}`


I am a newbie to LWC and Salesforce as a whole. I just wanted to execute this task I thought of. Can you please help me with correct code snippet OR mention where I need to make changes to get this done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only assume you did not update the whole method as shown?

Comment: I did, sir. I copied the entire snippet and pasted as it is. Yet, the error.

Comment: Is there some code you did not paste in your question? The snippet I provided does not reference `aVar0`.

Comment: @PhilW My guess is that they are not paying close attention to, well, pretty much anything. JavaScript, and programming in general, requires a close attention to detail. I would expect to see an error from the original along the lines of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`, because they forgot to use `this.`.

Comment: I missed it when correcting the data access.